# Representing the state of a tic tac toe board using a bitset; how to efficiently find neighboring states?

Tags: bit-manipulation, state, bit, bit-shift, bitset

I'm writing a state class that represents the state of a tic tac toe board. I want to find the neighboring states of the current state. The neighbors are basically the current state with the addition that one of the cells is filled.

Each cell can be "empty," "X", or "O." For each cell, I am using 2 bits to represent it:

```
00 (empty)

01 (filled by X)

10 (filled by O)
```

So for a 3x3 board, I will use 18 bits (I am aware of more memory efficient techniques, but this is sufficient for now).

There are 2 ways I can think of to get the neighboring states, and each with their pros and cons:

(1) I can find the empty cells by looping through the size 18 bitset, and check that both `state_in_bits[i]` and `state_in_bits[i+1]` are both zero for an even `i`. This is more memory efficient, but not as time efficient as (2).

(2) In my state class, I keep a representation of the empty cells either using ints or bits. With this approach, I can easily grab the empty cells. This is more memory intensive, but more time efficient.

These are the 2 approaches I came up with, and each with their pros and cons (albeit pretty minor), but I feel like there might be some kind of bit manipulation trick that I can use to do what I want. Any advice?